# Trying to undelete a file, says it can't find the file even though I see it in my log

Tags: git

I ran:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

and I see the deleted file:

```
commit  abc123abc123
..
some desc here


delete mode 100644 myapp/db/scripts/some_table.sql
```

so I try and get the file back:

```
>git checkout abc123abc123 myapp/db/scripts/some_table.sql
>error:  pathspec 'myapp/db/scripts/some_table.sql' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the commit **previous** to that one. `abc123abc123` is the commit where it was deleted. You want to checkout from the one **before** that.